# Regular Expression in Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qt5, qregularexpression

I am using Qt5.6.

I need to process the incoming data in a serial port, the data will be of the format "AD=+172345AD=+272345" and so on. I append the incoming data to a `QString` and using Regex to extract the decimals.

If I write a regular expression :

```
int tmp = StrData.indexOf(QRegularExpression("AD=\+[0-9]{6}"))
```

it doesn't match, i.e tmp is always -1. But I tested the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/lA2sD0/1), and I found it to be valid. What could be the issue?

Comment: Double the backslash (`\\+`) or put the `+` inside `[]` (`[+]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#indexOf-6), you can use the regex inside `QString.indexOf` to get the *index position of the first match of the regular expression `re` in the string*.

The only problem with the regex is that in Qt, the strings are C style, i.e. they can contain escape sequences. Thus, the backslashes escaping regex special characters must be doubled.

Use

```
QRegularExpression("AD=\\+[0-9]{6}")
```

or

```
QRegularExpression("AD=[+][0-9]{6}")
```

since inside `[...]`, the `+` is treated as a literal character.